# Deploying backend jobs in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I am very new to google app engine. 
    I have tried deploying web application into google app and its working fine.
    Now i have to work on deploying backend jobs (standalone java programs) into google app engine I am not finding a way to proceed with this.
    Please suggest me a solution for scheduling backend jobs using cron job in GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Backends are deprecated. You need to use App Engine Modules. This article explains how to deploy a module:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

If you are still using backends, however, you describe them in backends.xml file and deploy with the rest of your project.